# What is the range of Orisa's 'Halt!'?

Tags: overwatch

I want to know how far I can shoot Orisa's orb.

Sometimes, I aim near a bridge or the limit of the map to try to kill them, but I just move the enemy players a few meters to the ground.

So how far does it pull them?

Comment: Not an answer, just a recommendation - use the ability to pull enemies together so your team can combo. It's not good at trying to pull enemies off the map for kills as that was not the intention. - also the ability is called 'Halt!' https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/orisa/

Comment: @n_palum Sorry about my edit, yours was just fine before I changed the title.

Comment: @ИвоНедев No worries, I added the link just for clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the [wiki](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Orisa), the area of effect has a 7.5 meter radius.

This means it would pull any enemy 7.5 meters away from the orb towards it.

To get the distance into perspective **1 tracer blink** is 7 meters.

Of-course you need to detonate it when it's in range or pray any map obstacle it may hit is within the range so that you get any value out of it.

Comment: I would add that you have to detonate the orb, or it has to stick to something and detonate to activate this.

Comment: @n_palum Sounds good.

Comment: Well, know I'm gonna aim better. As my experience vs Orisa', I prefer to killing players detonating the orb on the limit of the map than grouping and killing it with ults. Your team gonna keep their ults and you just waste a skill with a low cd. Thx a lote mate.

Comment: To add to this: While the orb is flying, any targets that are in range of the orb's radius will have a small beam connecting them to the orb. This is simply a visual indicator that shows you: If the orb were to explode now, that target would be pulled into the orb.